# how to move the table inside of other table

Tags: html

i have the codes with many tables inside table.Here the second table has to come in the right side.Below is my code.

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The problem is i can not move to beside of right side of first table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `<td>` like below:

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>//see here the changes
<td>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

To learn more about HTML check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/)